# How continuously zoom in - zoom out TextView text Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make TextView Zoom in - Zoom out continuously in my app for that, I tried the following code but it works only once and I want it for infinite time. My code is---

```
private void setTvZoomInOutAnimation(final TextView textView) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final float startSize = 20;
        final float endSize = 13;
        final int animationDuration = 900; // Animation duration in ms

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startSize, endSize);
        animator.setDuration(animationDuration);

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) 
            {
                float animatedValue = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                textView.setTextSize(animatedValue);
            }
        });

        animator.start();
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code, you have missed the following line--

**//animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);  // Use this line for infinite animationsanimator.setRepeatCount(2);   // Use this for fix amount of time**

```
private void setTvZoomInOutAnimation(final TextView textView) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final float startSize = 20;
            final float endSize = 13;
            final int animationDuration = 900; // Animation duration in ms

            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startSize, endSize);
            animator.setDuration(animationDuration);

            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) 
                {
                    float animatedValue = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                    textView.setTextSize(animatedValue);
                }
            });

            //animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);  // Use this line for infinite animations
            animator.setRepeatCount(2);
            animator.start();
        }
```

Hope it will help..

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve your problem. I hope, it may work for you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView scaleText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scaleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        setTvZoomInOutAnimation(scaleText);
     }
    private void setTvZoomInOutAnimation(final TextView textView) {
        final float startSize = 20;
        final float endSize = 13;
        final int animationDuration = 900;
```

```
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startSize, endSize);
    animator.setDuration(animationDuration);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator)
        {
            float animatedValue = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            textView.setTextSize(animatedValue);
        }
    });
    animator.start();
}
```

}